# How can I use "git-svn" to checkout a local svn repository?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I'm practicing how to use svn and git.

I created a svn repository on my computer, at "/Users/name/svnRepo/test". I am able to use the svn commands to work on this repository.

Then, I tried to use command **"git-svn clone FILE:///Users/name/svnRepo/test/ ."**, and got an error:

**Initialized empty Git repository in ...
Bad URL passed to RA layer: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL: Local URL 'FILE:///Users/name/svnRepo/test' does not contain 'file://' prefix at /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1775**

Could anyone help?

Comment: did you try with lowercase file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Scheme part of URL is case-sensitive. Try to use "git-svn clone **file://**/Users/name/svnRepo/test/ ." command.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a local SVN repository with git-svn on Windows, you need to use a downgraded version of the repository until this bug which is marked as wontfix is fixed https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=253

```
svnadmin create c:\repo --pre-1.4-compatible
```

Then load up the repository using a dump file

```
svnadmin load C:\repo < svn.dump
```

Once you have that done you can use the following command

```
git svn clone file:///c/repo git-repo
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem too. I am running on windows.

I did a work around, I downloaded the [VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com) and pointed that to where my repositories were.

I then needed to add a user to the svn server so that I could pull from it.

Then instead of trying to run this command

```
git svn clone file:///F:/Repositories/Main/SubProj --stdlayout SubProj
```

i ran this command instead

```
git svn clone https://localhost/svn/Main/SubProj --stdlayout SubProj
```

which worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Under windows, the magical incantation that does the trick is as follows:

```
git svn clone file:///c/Users/name/...
```

In other words, after `file:` you need three slashes, then a `c`, (assuming you are working on drive `C:`,) then one more slash instead of a colon, then the rest of the path.