# How do I clone a git repo from a local svn repo

Tags: git-svn

I want to learn to use `git-svn`. I have an svn local repository on my disk that I've checked out a while ago using something like this:

```
svn co http://myserver.com/mysvnrepo/trunk/ /mysvnrepo/
ls -a /mysvnrepo/
.     ..     .svn     foo     bar
```

This `/mysvnrepo/` is HUGE, so I want to avoid re-downloading or copying the files at all costs.

I'm wondering if there's a way to `git clone` this local repo without downloading / copying anything (because it's already there).

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198331/how-can-i-use-git-svn-to-checkout-a-local-svn-repository) which seems to be what I'm looking for, but when I do that it doesn't quite give me what I expect.

```
cd /mysvnrepo/
git svn clone file://mysvnrepo/
ls /mysvnrepo/
.     ..     .git     .svn     foo     bar
git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .svn/
#   foo/
#   bar/
```

I would expect `git` to detect `foo` and `bar` as "versioned and up-to-date".

According to the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) it seems that I need to use `git svn init` because `git svn clone` runs a `fetch`, which I certainly don't want. So I tried

```
git svn init --trunk=file:///mysvnrepo/
```

...but no luck.

I'm completely new to `git`, so my confusion is off-the-charts... am I doing something utterly wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take a subversion snapshot and convert it into a git repository.

It sounds like you are trying to avoid a lengthy initialization of the git repository from svn: which ordinarily will try to ready your entire history.  This can be done in another way, by limiting the fetch to recent history depending on how much history is relevant to you:

```
git svn clone -s -r 12334:HEAD https://svn.host.org/repo
```

Where 12334 is the earliest svn revision you are interested in and assuming that the repo is laid out in a standard svn way with branches and tags.

Comment: Thanks andygavin... I did find out about this and it's the best I could do, but sadly it still re-downloads all the files, which is what I wanted to avoid doing.