# Converting local SVN checkout to Git

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have checked out the source from my old svn server but we are migrating to git. I don't have a version of SVN running on my machine. I want to clone what I have using Git svn clone but i am getting a bad url passed to ra layer error message.

Do I need to have svn running on my local machine to do this?

Should i just add the files to a repo and commit them that way ignoring all of the data that would be stored from using git svn clone?

Thanks for all of the advice

```
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///H:/DigitalFly/DigitalFly': Unable to open repository 'file:///H:/DigitalFly/DigitalFly' at /mingw32/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 148.

Bad URL passed to RA layer: Illegal repository URL 'H:\DigitalFly\DigitalFly' at /mingw32/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 148.
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message please?

Comment: Those are the two errors I ran into

Comment: possibly related: [How can I use “git-svn” to checkout a local svn repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198331/how-can-i-use-git-svn-to-checkout-a-local-svn-repository) (looks like your URL is not correctly formatted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can't clone Working Copy, only real repository
- For repository on local FS (when you'll have it) you have to use `file:///` URL

Comment: So if I have used checkout I'll have a working copy right? Is there an easy way to check if I have a real repo or a working copy. Sorry if these are stupid questions I'm not too familiar with svn

Comment: @ArachnidHivemind - "checked out the source from my old svn server" == have only working copy

Comment: I see. Is there any downside to taking the working copy and creating a new git repo with it and committing it? I'll probably lose the logs from the old svn repo but if those aren't crucial that would work right?